# string concatenation with special characters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to understand something. I am trying to concatenate a string like this:

```
$Uri = "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67158107"
$extras = "something"
    
"Download $Uri?extra=$extras"
```

but then as a result I get: `?extra=something`
I can get it working if I wrap `$Uri` with `$()` or `${}` but my question is why do I need to wrap it any what is the difference between wrapping it with `()` and `{}`?

Comment: Please add some details: What is your input for `$Uri`, `$extras`? What exactly do you expect as output?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. It works with any input, I have added dummy input that gives expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell allows a user to use special characters in variable names. For example,
`$URI?extra` in your case is a single variable which is allowed in powershell. Even spaces are allowed in a variable. For example, `${This is my variable name}` is a valid Powershell variable name.

The difference between `${}` and `$()` is that `{}` is used for variables with special characters and `()` is used to invoke certain commands. For example if my clipboard has something like this:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158107/string-concatenation-with-special-characters`

Then you should use `"Download $(Get-Clipboard)"` to get something like
`Download https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158107/string-concatenation-with-special-characters`

Comment: hey, thanks for a quick response. In my example `$URI` does not have special characters so in this sense should () or {} be appropriate to use?

Comment: The latter like this
`"Download ${URI}?extra=$extras"`

Eventhough your defined variable `$URI` doesn't have any special characters, in the string above, the `?` is also taken as a part of the variable. So the latter is suitable here.

Answer (score 2):

Personnaly i use always [format](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx) operator like this :

```
"Download {0}?extra={1}" -f $Uri, $extras
```

With a function :

```
function BuildURL($Uri, $extras)
{
"{0}?extra={1}" -f $Uri, $extras
}

$Result=BuildURL -Uri 'https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67158107' -extras 'something'

$Result
```

Comment: how would pass the result of this string into a function? would you then have to story in a temporary variable?

Comment: look my answer.